# Access SharePoint REST API with certificate based client credentials (replacing deprecated ACS)

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, jwt, postman, sharepoint-online

We want to access SharePoint REST API with certificate based client credentials (replacing deprecated ACS).

For now we not able to get an access token from token endpoint.

Even though we:

- uploaded a certificate to the registered application,
- enabled app roles and api permissions with granted admin consent

We keep seeing this exception with a jwt token in postman:

> 'AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client
> assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not
> found., Thumbprint of key used by client:
> 'D7A075E3A[...]F45F75F39DFAF', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph
> Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id
> 'a4f[...]'

We do not know the thumbprint of the key. We are glad for any suggestions where to look as we have been through ms docs and old stack suggestions.

We went through the integration assistant, ms docs e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service or copilot. we struggle to understand where this wrong thumbprint is coming from.

**Postman call:**

```
POST /622d2..d28d/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.35.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 6eb86bfb..b982cf90
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1042
Cookie: fpc=AnJUj6Foo6JHu93Jqm..DdB90OAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd
 
client_id=a4f1[...]&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Ik[...]&scope=https%3A%2F%2Ft[..]n.sharepoint.com%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
x-ms-request-id: fd41f6c6-e80a-465b-b6de-effd5de74a00
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.16878.5 - WEULR1 ProdSlices
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Set-Cookie: fpc=AnJUj6Foo6JHu93JqmIgZdyfiZiWAwAAAIDdB90OAAAA; expires=Tue, 09-Jan-2024 16:28:44 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2023 16:28:44 GMT
Content-Length: 1146
 

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: The certificate with identifier used to sign the client assertion is not registered on application. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '0BA07DD820C5F4[..]5E3AF40105EB6', Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id 'a4[...]'. Review the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the corresponding service endpoint and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appli...']. Trace ID: fd41f6c6-e80a-465.. Correlation ID: a5e2.. Timestamp: 2023-12-10 16:28:44Z","error_codes":[700027],"timestamp":"2023-12-10 16:28:44Z","trace_id":"fd41f...fd5de74a00","correlation_id":"a5e...4c7d2","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700027"}
```

Answer (score 1):

We were able to solve the issue and it's quite banal. The private.key was missing password protection. Reexport with password protection solved the behaviour.